# Transporting a big shipment of computer equipment to the Caribbean

Tags: caribbean, freighter-travel, shipping

I'm travelling to the Caribbean and need to bring with me about ten heavy desktop computers with CRT monitors. I understand this is a lot of weight and will take up a lot of space. In fact, from a cursory perusal of airline baggage policies it doesn't look as though I will be able to check it.

How can I get ten computers and myself from Portland, Oregon to the Dominican Republic?

Comment: CRTs are really really heavy, and new LCD screens are pretty cheap... Is there a reason why you're not just chucking the CRTs in the bin, and buying some cheap new or 2nd hand LCDs out there?

Comment: The equipment is donated. Beggars can't be choosers :-/

Comment: This question is an issue of shippping business equipment and not really related to an issue of Travel. I'm sorry, but I have to close this as off topic.

Comment: I do see this as a genuine on-topic question. Main travelers are faced with problems with sending large amounts of bagage to their destination.

Comment: You definitely won't be able to check it in. Shipping it is your only option. There are no doubt many shipping options including using the same airline you're flying with. But our superiors have deemed anything related to shipping as not related to travel even when you're trying to travel with stuff \-:

Comment: CRTs are heavy and heavy stuff is expensive to ship. Yet somehow the majority of dead CRTs in the west somehow end up shipped to developing nations where they become toxic junk. I have no idea how the economics of that works out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't get it on the plane, you'll need to contact a "freight forwarder." Check your local phone book. It's probably not going to be cheap--expect to pay several times more per kilogram than you would for excessive baggage on an airplane. Also, since it is "unaccompanied baggage" you may have significant hassles and fees with customs. The freight forwarder should be able to advise you the details. Frankly, I agree with Gagravar--I don't think shipping CRT monitors like this makes any sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with the Dominican Republic, but I did send some equipment with oversea shipments to Suriname, from Europe. When you send a package per ship, you often not pay per kg, but per volume. Try "shipment dominican republic" in google. It could take up to 6 weeks to arrive though, depending on the shipping schedule.

Comment: +1 for "by volume". Years ago I looked at bringing a car I bought in the US back to Australia and the amount of space it took up in the container was the major factor.